# Reorder columns in a matrix

Tags: r

Suppose that I have an `n` row, `m` column matrix `A`, and I want to reorder every column in `m` according to the sorting of some specific row.

For instance, if I take `order(A[,k])`, that gives me the numeric or alphabetical order of elements in column `k`. I now want to sort every column in matrix `A` according to those rankings, so that elements `1...n` in every row are ordered to correspond to elements `1...n` (by rank) in column `k`. Is there a simple way to do this without looping over all columns?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't `A[order(A[,k]),]` do what you want?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried, and it didn't work. For instance, if I have a 2x3 matrix X and call x[order(x[,2])], the output is a vector, not the entire matrix.

Comment: That's because you're missing the last comma.

Comment: That was a typo. x[,order(x[,2])] returns a partial matrix (2x2 rather than a reordered 2x3, so it still doesn't work.

Comment: Specifically, let's take xmat=matrix(c(1,2,4,3,5,6),nrow=2,ncol=3). I take order(x[,2]), giving me 2 1. I now have x[,order(x[,2])], which gives me a 2x2 matrix as output.

Comment: You said you wanted to order the rows, but your code is ordering the columns.  My code orders the rows.

Comment: C'mon Joshua... post as an answer so it can get accepted and displayed as such.

Comment: @DWin: sorry, sorry... old habits and all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use:

```
A[order(A[,k]),]
```

For example:

```
set.seed(21)
A <- matrix(rnorm(50),10,5)
A[order(A[,1]),]
```

Answer (score 7):

to elaborate on @joshua's answer:  I think the confusion may arise from the fact that you are ordering on a ***column*** but then passing that ordering as an index to the ***rows***.

That's likely why you tried `A[, order(A[,k])]`  instead of  `A[order(A[,k]),]`

`order(x)` contrary to the name, does not actually ***order*** `x`, but rather
 just provides an ***ordering to*** `x`.

---

**For example:**

```
set.seed(1)
A <- matrix(sample(LETTERS[2:8], 24, T), ncol=6)
print(A, quote=F)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] C    C    F    F    G    H   
[2,] D    H    B    D    H    C   
[3,] F    H    C    G    D    F   
[4,] H    F    C    E    G    B    


order(A[, 2])
[1] 1 4 2 3
```

***Note that the output is only 4 elements long, which is the number of *rows* of A, not columns.***

The output essentially says that within column 2 of A,

- the 1st element goes first,
- the 4th element goes second,
- the 2nd element goes thrid,
- etc..

But each element of column A is attached to a row. We need to re-order the rows not the columns.

To apply that ordering to the entire matrix (or data frame), we use the ordering as a row index:

```
rowIndex <- order(A[, 2])

# Note that these are all equivalent
A[rowIndex,  ]
A[order(A[, 2]),  ]
A[c(1, 4, 1, 3),  ]
```

Lastly, we can pass `order()` more than one vector, and it will use subsequent vectors to break ties.
However, regardless of the number of columns from A we give it, `order` will still give us a single vector, equal in size to the number of rows of A:

```
# Order according to column 2; ties are left according to their original order
order(A[, 2])
[1] 1 4 2 3

# Order according to column 2; ties are ordered according to column 5
order(A[, 2], A[, 5])
[1] 1 4 3 2
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. Imagine I have a correlation matrix (elements a-d as rows, a-d as column, and I want to reorder the matrix (both columns and rows) according to the variable k that specifies the order (e.g., d,a,b,d instead of a,b,c,d)) -- how would I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Torvon, you can post your comment as a new question here on stack overflow, simply linking back to this old one.

Comment: Always scared to post probably ridiculously easy new stuff .. will do