# Sorting a matrix with order, using all columns, when you don't know the number of columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is generated dynamically from recursive left join, how can I use the `order` function to apply on all columns when I don't know in advance the number of columns ? I want the result sorted first on first column, then on the second ...

In the example below, I have four columns

```
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(rep(1:25,4)[order(rnorm(100))],ncol=4)
B <- A[order(A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4],decreasing=TRUE),]
```

So I wrote this `A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4]` but how do I do if I don't know the number of columns ?

Comment: My first hunch was to replace `A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4]` with `A[, 1:ncol(A)]` but that gives me an indexing error...

Comment: See possible answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691003/reorder-columns-in-a-matrix)

Comment: @Jamie thank you for the link

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508352/how-to-sort-a-matrix-by-all-columns)

Comment: Thanks @alexis I didn't find this while searching for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create string like `A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4]` in loop and next use `parse` and `eval` function to evaluate your expression.

```
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(rep(1:25,4)[order(rnorm(100))],ncol=4)
col <- ""
for (i in 1:ncol(A)){
  col <- paste(col,paste0('A[,',i,']'), sep = ",")
}
## remove first comma
col <- substr(col, 2, nchar(col))
col
[1] "A[,1],A[,2],A[,3],A[,4]"
B <- eval(parse(text = paste("A[order(",col,",decreasing=TRUE),]")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I took Glaud's answer and added a couple tweaks:

You can do the whole thing in one line without using a for loop.

```
eval(parse(text = paste("A[order(",paste(paste0("A[,",1:ncol(A1),"]"), collapse = ","),",decreasing=TRUE),]")))
```

The following bit will get you the list of columns (which I then replaced Glaud's col for loop with):

```
paste(paste0("A[,",1:ncol(A1),"]"), collapse = ",")
```

I think it'd be cool to functionitize it which I can add to this post in a bit